# Receiving broadcast in bash

Tags: bash, netcat, socat

**What is the correct way to receive UDP broadcast packets in netcat or socat?**

I would like to send broadcast from one computer to another in bash. Sending works well with:

```
socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:50011,broadcast
```

But (in both cases) receiving freezes when first line (packet) received:

```
nc -luk 50011
```

or

```
socat - UDP-LISTEN:50011
```

I think that the UDP connection ends, but the receiving side does not hang or does not start to listen to new packets. It is still waiting for the first connection (ignoring new connections).

Comment: I've had similar issues and managed to fix it with `nc -lukw 0 <port>`, even though `man nc` specifically states that `-l` and `-w` cannot be combined. So the `man` page says one thing, but what `nc` actually does when given both `-l` and `-w` is different, at least on my machine. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have solved it using my own script in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from socket import *
import sys

if (len(sys.argv)==3 and sys.argv[1]=='-l'):
    try:
        port=int(sys.argv[2])
    except ValueError as verr:
        print('Invalid port number')
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.bind(('',port))
        while True:
            data,address=s.recvfrom(1024)
            print((data.decode('utf-8')).rstrip())
        s.close()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        s.close()
        print('Exit on Keyboard Interrupt')

else:
        print('UDP socket listener by JirkaRCK v1.0\nArguments:\n-l Listen on specific UDP port')
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `UDP-LISTEN`, you can use `UDP-RECV` to stream the UDP output

So your command would be:

`socat - udp-recv:50011`

To capture the output you can use tee

`socat - udp-recv:50011 | tee /tmp/udp_recv.txt`

Alternately, if you want to stream the output in a more consistent way, you can set up a named pipe and listen to/capture the output

```
#(re)create a named pipe (you can use "mkfifo <file>" 
#instead of "mknod <file> p" if available)
#we test if the file is a named pipe "[ -p <file> ]", 
#if not, delete any existing and create it
[ -p /tmp/udp_recv.fifo ] || (rm -f /tmp/udp_recv.fifo; mknod /tmp/udp_recv.fifo p)

#socat should continue to send received output to the pipe file 
#and block the loop from iterating but if it fails/exits it will
#start again when the loop iterates. 
#socat will only run one instance per port/address, 
#so it won't start a new one unless it's not running.
# "-b 1024" on the socat command tells it to 
#buffer only 1024 bytes rather than 8192 (default)
while : ; do 
  socat -b 1024 - udp-recv:50011 > /tmp/udp_recv.fifo
  sleep 1
done
```

you can get/capture the output in another terminal with cat, tee or another loop (`while read line; do ...`)

`cat /tmp/udp_recv.fifo`
or
`cat /tmp/udp_recv.fifo | tee /tmp/udp_recv.txt`

Note that when you interrupt `cat` (or anything else that opens the pipe file), the closure of the fifo pipe will cause socat to exit and show an error (Broken pipe) since there's nothing to listen to the output in the named pipe file, but since it's in the while loop as soon as something starts listening to the pipe file again it'll run and stream to it.

If you wanted to run it in the background you can put your streamer (the socat while loop) into a script and run it:

`nohup udpstream.sh &`

`nohup` tells the process to stop responding to SIGHUP (i.e. you hangup/close your terminal) and `&` puts it in the background. Output that would have shown in your terminal will go into a file named `./nohup.out`